# Retrieving a Large Data Set to be Shared Across Multiple Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application built on AngularJS which retrieves a large amount of data via a RESTful web service at regular intervals (every second, 500 kb - 1 Mb).  I have a central service which is responsible for retrieving that data.  When data is successfully retrieved by the service, the service breaks up the data into logical chunks and broadcasts that the data is available.  This broad cast is picked up by a number of controllers and displayed as necessary.

Since this single service is handling the retrieval and the logical grouping of the data, it is doing quite a lot and has become very complicated.  Is there a better way to do this?  Should my retrieval service use other services to distribute the data to those individual controllers?  This makes more sense to me, but I worry about data copies and memory.  Are these concerns well-founded?

Comment: Are you using `$resource` or something like restacular?

Comment: Hmmmm...no. I am using the low level ``$http.get(...)`` to retrieve data.  It looks like ``$resource`` is just a high-level wrapper for the ``$http`` methods, no?

Answer (score 1):

In response to...

> I have a central service which is responsible for retrieving that
>   data. When data is successfully retrieved by the service, the service
>   breaks up the data into logical chunks and broadcasts that the data is
>   available.

...and...

> Since this single service is handling the retrieval and the logical
>   grouping of the data, it is doing quite a lot and has become very
>   complicated. Is there a better way to do this? Should my retrieval
>   service use other services to distribute the data to those individual
>   controllers?

...generally, it is good to have [single-responsibility](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#single-responsibility) files--that is, one responsibility per component (e.g., controller, factory) per file. So with regard to your queries, then this is a good paradigm to follow. Two separate services may be implemented where one takes care of the logical chunking of data, while the other handles broadcasting data availability.

I also suggest checking out the following guidelines as these could greatly help in writing your code.

- [Factories](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#factories)
- [Data Services](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#data-services)

As for data copy and memory concerns, it's a good thing to keep these in mind--avoiding coding styles and patterns which are known to cause such issues. Still, it is better to try and implement first and see if such problems will be encountered along the way. And then, start from there.